# Delete files from md5 list in HashSet

Tags: java, file, path, md5, hashset

I want to delete file located in local machine, comparing to server machine.

My example :

```
import java.io.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        Set<String > lmd5 = new HashSet<String>();
            lmd5.add("4be1babb2f8cac64d96f8052c0942130");
            lmd5.add("a7514d56f233a434c7066176933d708d");
            lmd5.add("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e");
            lmd5.add("674e3b94be9ed5db8bafe75808385de1");
        Set<String > dmd5 = new HashSet<String>();
            dmd5.add("4be1babb2f8cac64d96f8052c0942130");
            dmd5.add("a7514d56f233a434c7066176933d708d");
            dmd5.add("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e");

        if(lmd5.equals(dmd5)){
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else{
            lmd5.removeAll(dmd5);

            System.out.println("Obsoletes Files To Delete : " + lmd5);

            File[] paths = baseModDirectoryFile.listFiles();
            for(File path:paths){
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            String md5 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
                if(lmd5.contains(md5) ){
                    File foundFile = path;
                    System.out.println("Obsolete File Found !");
                    try{
                        if(foundFile.delete()){
                            System.out.println("Obsolete File Deleted !");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Obsolete File Not Deleted : Error !");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

In my output console, I have the message "Obsoletes Files Found" which appears, but after that I have the message : "Obsolete File Not Deleted". I believe I arrive too late in the function to delete the file, as all files have already been checked.

Maybe I have to review this position but I would like to get some advise.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the value of foundFile.delete()?

Do you have enough permission to delete file?

May be your file is being locked by your FileInputStream?

Comment: In my application, lmd5 and dmd5 vars are equals to the return of a hashset in another method. I'm gonna edit my question for you.

Comment: 1) Try catching an exception

2) Are you sure you are not deleting directory? If it is a directory make sure it is empty.

Comment: It's a txt file, and I added the try catch for the delete condition but there's no error to print. I think it's the lmd5.contains(md5) line which doesn't store the path associated for the rest of the method.

Comment: What is the return value of foundFile.delete()?

try print the path of the file System.out.println(foundfile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: I checked it too and the path is well printed : C:\Users\01\AppData\Roaming\.application\mods\aaaa.txt. Ialso tested in other folder than appdata but it's the same.

Comment: You're right it was my FileInputStream which forbid deleting files till it was not close. But I had a FIS in other method used in the main class so I had to close both FIS. Thank you, I 'm gonna post it.